# Selecting Elements from a List in Racket

Tags: racket

I have a function in Racket which takes a list, iterates through it, checks each item in the list against a condition, and is intended to output a list of the index of every item for which this condition is true. I cannot use indexes-of.

Currently, my setup is:

```
(define (function lst)
  (define output empty)
  (for ([i (length lst)])
        (cond
          [(CONDITION) (append output (list i))]
        )
    )
  output
)
```

This outputs an empty list. I (think I) understand the reason why; append doesn't actually append to the variable output (the way one would expect in, say, Python), rather concatenates its parameters as a new list. I do not know how to fix this. Again, I'm trying to fetch indexes, so it's important those remain intact.

I have verified my condition functions properly; this does correctly identify each item, it's getting it into a returnable list that's the issue at this juncture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists in Racket (Unlike regular Scheme) are immutable, and `append` in both always returns a fresh list anyways. The plain `for` comprehension you're using doesn't return any value, either.

There's quite a few ways to do what you want without `indexes-of` (Though that's the easy way). For example, using `for/list` with a `#:when` clause to select just the elements that `CONDITION` returns true for:

```lisp
(define (function lst)
  (for/list ([elem (in-list lst)]
             [i (in-naturals)]
             #:when (CONDITION elem))
    i))
```

Comment: (If this is for homework (Which I suspect it is given the restriction about not using `indexes-of`), I'd be surprised if this would be accepted, though. Most classes seem to shy away from fancier Racket features like for)

Comment: You'd assume correctly! I do think this implementation would be fine – the restrictions are specifically enumerated and this does not violate them. Even so, I was able to figure out for on my own (even if I was misusing it), I'd argue that this for/list approach isn't unreasonable.

Just to make sure I understand: this for/list iterates over the elements of lst and over natural numbers, and adds the natural number to a list when CONDITION is met, a list which it returns? 

The Racket documentation and I have some...differences, mostly due to me not understanding functional programming.

Comment: @JaySay Correct.